# Trying to link two models with a ForeignKey but get the error "IntegrityError NOT NULL"

Tags: python, django

I have a model where a user posts a job vacancy, then other users can submit applications. The submit application model is called 'CandidatesSubmission' & pulls the 'title' from a different app/model 'JobPosts'.

I can add submit applications through the ADMIN page fine, but when trying to do so with a form I get "IntegrityError NOT NULL constraint failed: candidates_candidatessubmission.title_id."

I believe that I'm missing something in my Views.py that essentially says "use the title of job vacancy as the title field.

I have tried adding null=True, blank=False but which stops the error but the title isn't saved to the database.

Any suggestions on what I'm doing wrong would be great. Thank you

**models.py**

```
class CandidatesSubmission(models.Model):

    title                   = models.ForeignKey('jobs.JobsPost', on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    Fee                     = models.CharField(max_length=50, null=False, blank=False)
    CandidateFirstName      = models.CharField(max_length=50, null=True, blank=False)
    CandidateSecondName     = models.CharField(max_length=50, null=True, blank=False)
    created                 = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    author                  = models.ForeignKey(settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
```

**views.py**

```
from django.shortcuts import render, redirect, get_object_or_404
from django.db.models import Q
from django.http import HttpResponseNotFound
from jobs.models import JobsPost
from candidates.models import CandidatesSubmission
from candidates.forms import CreateCandidatePostForm
from account.models import Account

from operator import attrgetter

# Create your views here.
def submit_candidates_view(request, slug):

    context = {}

    user = request.user
    if not user.is_authenticated:
        return redirect('must_authenticate')

    form = CreateCandidatePostForm(request.POST or None, request.FILES or None)
    if form.is_valid():
        obj = form.save(commit=False)
        author = Account.objects.filter(email=user.email).first()
        obj.author = author
        
        obj.save()
        form = CreateCandidatePostForm()

    context['form'] = form

    accounts = CandidatesSubmission.objects.all()
    context['accounts'] = accounts

    return render(request, 'candidates/submit_candidates.html', context)


def response_view(request):

    context = {}

    accounts = CandidatesSubmission.objects.all()
    context['accounts'] = accounts


    return render(request, "candidates/response.html", context)
```

**forms.py**

```
from django import forms

from candidates.models import CandidatesSubmission

class CreateCandidatePostForm(forms.ModelForm):


    class Meta:
        model = CandidatesSubmission
        fields = ['Fee', 'CandidateFirstName', 'CandidateSecondName']

    def save(self, commit=True):
        submission_post = self.instance
        submission_post.Fee = self.cleaned_data['Fee']
        submission_post.CandidateFirstName = self.cleaned_data['CandidateFirstName']
        submission_post.CandidateSecondName = self.cleaned_data['CandidateSecondName']
        if commit:
            submission_post.save()
        return submission_post
```

Comment: You describe fields which you want to save in your form `['Fee', 'CandidateFirstName', 'CandidateSecondName']`, so you don't save `title` to database. You need to change title in your `save` form method if you want to fill it some one, without allowing user to choose it

Comment: @AndreyMaslov So the 'title' field comes from another model -- how would I go about displaying the title along with the 'Fee' 'CandidateFirstName' and 'CandidateSecondName'?

Comment: you can edit it as any other field and user will select needed title from another model. if you don't want user to select it and want to fill it manually then you need update your `save` form method to read requiered title from other model and put it here

Comment: I think I understand. I added title = JobsPost.objects.filter().last() which solves the Null issue. Obviously it's taking the .last() but I want it to take the current title. Any suggestions here? Thanks for you help so far.

Comment: added answer. check it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

if you have "current" title, so your `slug` might store it, so you can use it like that.

```
def submit_candidates_view(request, slug):
    context = {}
    user = request.user
    if not user.is_authenticated:
        return redirect('must_authenticate')

    form = CreateCandidatePostForm(post_slug=slug, request.POST or None, request.FILES or None)
    if form.is_valid():
        obj = form.save(commit=False)
        author = Account.objects.filter(email=user.email).first()
        obj.author = author
        
        obj.save()
        form = CreateCandidatePostForm()

    context['form'] = form

    accounts = CandidatesSubmission.objects.all()
    context['accounts'] = accounts

    return render(request, 'candidates/submit_candidates.html', context)
```

in your forms.py we replace `__init__` method to receive slug of your title

```
class CreateCandidatePostForm(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = CandidatesSubmission
        fields = ['Fee', 'CandidateFirstName', 'CandidateSecondName']

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        self.post_slug = kwargs.pop("post_slug", None)
        super().__init__(*args, **kwargs)

    def save(self, commit=True):
        submission_post = self.instance
        submission_post.title = JobsPost.objects.get(slug=self.post_slug)
        if commit:
            submission_post.save()
        return submission_post
```

Comment: This worked perfectly!!! Thank you so much for your help! You have no idea how stuck I was...